# Select all records of a type

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I'm trying to get all records of specific type from RavenDB with C#.

When I'm using Lucene:

```
 var serviceTraces = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<ServiceTrace>("IDLoadDateIndex").Take(50);
```

I'm getting the results in:

serviceTraces.QueryResult.Results

When I'm not using Lucene:

```
var serviceTraces = session.Query<ServiceTrace>("IDLoadDateIndex").Take(50);
```

I'm not getting any results and an exception is thrown when trying to perform "ToList()" on "serviceTraces" object.

Why is that ?

**UPDATE:**

ServiceTrace class:

```
public class ServiceTrace
    {
        public ServiceTrace(ServiceDeployment sd)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.ServiceDeploymentID = sd.Id;
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string TransactionID { get; set; }
        public string ParentTransactionID { get; set; }
        public string RequestID { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationCode { get; set; }
        public int InstituteCode { get; set; }
        public string ServiceDeploymentID { get; set; }
        public string UserHostAddress { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequestDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ResponseDateTime { get; set; }
        public string RequestBody { get; set; }
        public string ResponseBody { get; set; }
        public string Key1Value { get; set; }
        public string Key2Value { get; set; }
        public string Key3Value { get; set; }
        public string Key4Value { get; set; }
        public string Key5Value { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
        public string FullExceptionText { get; set; }
        public DateTime LoadDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActivationDateTime { get; set; }
        public string HostAddress { get; set; }
        public string BpmID { get; set; }
        public DateTime PreProcessDatetime { get; set; }
        public string DestHostAddress { get; set; }
        public string ArchivePath { get; set; }
        public string BTInstanceID { get; set; }
        public string Temp1 { get; set; }
        public string ExternalComponentDuration { get; set; }
        public string SQLIdentity { get; set; }
        public string ExceptionCode { get; set; }
        public string CertificateID { get; set; }
        public string ExternalComponentType { get; set; }
        public string ActivationID { get; set; }
    }
```

IDLoadDateIndex:

```
public class IDLoadDateIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ServiceTrace>
    {
        public IDLoadDateIndex()
        {
            Map = serviceTrace => from st in serviceTrace
                                  select new { LoadDate = st.LoadDate };
            Index(x => x.LoadDate, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?  And what does the `IDLoadDateIndex` look like?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but you shouldn't be marking a `DateTime` field as analyzed.  That makes no sense.  Delete that line from your index.  Also, please post the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a default constructor:

```
public ServiceTrace()
{
}
```

because when getting the data from RavenDB, the engine initialize a new instance by:

```
public ServiceTrace(ServiceDeployment sd)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.ServiceDeploymentID = sd.Id;
        }
```

and the ServiceDeployment object is a null reference .

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you need to call ToList on the serviceTraces

Comment: When doing this on both cases, I'm getting "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the constructor of ServiceTrace, regarding the object of ServiceDeployment